# Destructuring property of type `X | undefined` with a default

Tags: typescript, object-destructuring

I have

```
interface Foo {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

interface Bar {
  foo: Foo | undefined;
}

declare const useBar: () => Bar;

const f = () => {
  const { foo } = useBar();

  // ...
}
```

I can use `foo?.x` to access properties and this works. But in practice `foo` has a lot more properties and I'd like to avoid `?.` everywhere.

In JavaScript I can write

```
const { foo = {} } = useBar();
```

and then use `foo.x` and `foo.y` safely (in TypeScript terms, the type of `foo` is now `Partial<Foo>`). In TS this [gives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANy4C%20uuoksiKAQnFDvshiZSGLAB9k5EABMIMUBGkNmuWQgA2vFAnQgAzmGSU4Aawg8opABQBKZAF4AfMgsNcO-YZgPkth87wCDwMcQUwfbEZkKPsjU3NeWzcg3RDCHyF0ADpCZVwgA)

```
Property 'x' does not exist on type '{}'
```

Reasonable, but is there a way to avoid this problem and get a `Partial<Foo>` anyway?

I see that

```
const { foo: { x, y } = {} } = useBar();
```

does work, but isn't ideal for my real use case; I'd have to rename them like

```
const { foo: { x: fooX, y: fooY } = {} } = useBar();
```

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing the question gave me an answer which works but I'm still hoping for something nicer:

```
const { foo = {} as Partial<Foo> } = useBar();
```

EDIT: [improved version](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChnIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANy4C%20uuoksiKAQnFDvshiZSGLAB9k5EABMIMUBGkNmuBOhABnMGXSjSABV5hgcADYAeUQD5kAXhyMGuWQlO8UazdvIaIPKKQAFACUdjb%20Tp5agnbIIWH8BFHa2IKYsSC66YyxPn68IU5J6tGEsULoAHSEyrhAA)

where `noFoo` would be in the same module as `useBar`.

Comment: Can you explain why this isn't "nice"? I think this is the approach I'd take, so it would be good to understand what you're looking to improve.

Comment: Just seems too wordy to repeat on most uses of the function (and with a much longer name than `Foo`). Actually, this gives an idea: just declare `{} as Partial<Foo>` as a constant in the same module as `useBar`, and it can have a nice short name.